# Why do variables inside this for loop return null?

Tags: php, database

I have the following code and it's giving me hell of a time as to why the variables inside the `for ($x = 1; $x <= $quantity; $x++)` loop are not returning anything but `null` when called in the database insert query that's following it, or when I try to debug with `var_dump($cVnum);` for instance.

Here is the code:

```
if ($cash >= $product['cost'] * $quantity) {
    // Substract cash
    $receiver = $userData['login'];
    if ($receiver != "") {
        //all variables safe
        $database->setDB("account")->mkquery("UPDATE {{table}} SET ".$cashfield." = (".$cashfield." - ".$product['cost'] * $quantity.") WHERE id = '".$accountid."' LIMIT 1", "account");
        // For each quantity
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $quantity; $x++) {
            // Insert vnums to item_award
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
                $cVnum = $product['vnum'.$i];
                if ($cVnum > 0)  {
                    $socket0 = 0;
                    $socket2 = 0;
                    if ($product['vnum'.$i.'_time'] > 0) {
                        if ($cVnum == 72701 || ($cVnum > 71069 && $cVnum < 71075) || ($cVnum > 72722 && $cVnum < 72731)) {
                            $socket2 = $product['vnum'.$i.'_time'];
                        } else if ($cVnum == 47001 ||
                            ($cVnum > 41136 && $cVnum < 41145) ||
                            ($cVnum > 45078 && $cVnum < 45084) ||
                            ($cVnum > 71164 && $cVnum < 71168) ||
                            ($cVnum >= 45139 && $cVnum <= 45144) ||
                            ($cVnum >= 41311 && $cVnum <= 41314)) {
                                $socket0 = time() + ($product['vnum'.$i.'_time']*60*60*24);
                        } else {
                            $socket2 = time() + ($product['vnum'.$i.'_time']*60*60*24);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }                              
        $database->setDB("player");
        $insert = [
            "login" => $receiver, 
            "vnum" => $cVnum, 
            "count" => $quantity, 
            "given_time" => array("func", "NOW()"),
            "socket0" => 22, 
            "mall" => 1
        ];    
        $logok = $database->insert($insert, "item_award");
    }
}
```

I've been at it for like six hours now and can't figure out what's wrong.

**UPDATE**: I narrowed down where the problem is with `$cVnum = $product['vnum'.$i];`. I noticed that when I removed `$i` and it became `$product['vnum']` the variable returned the value I expected. Could there be a fix so that I can use with the `$i` variable though? Why is it returning `null` when `$i` variable is included?

Comment: Is that considered inappropriate? Sorry I don't know, im learning php

Comment: One simple suggestion. Divide and conquer when trying to debug something.

Comment: @NewbieJavaDeveloper there's `||` and `OR` in php and they have different operator precedence. Hell yeah ...

Comment: As long as you're not telling us what is in the `$product` variable, this question remains unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

With String Operators you have to use double quotes if you want PHP parse your variable : `$cVnum = $product["vnum".$i];`

Comment: No, that's only when you have a variable inside the quotes.